# MySQL design tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

We have 3 tables.

```
Instructor
ID (PK, AI)
Name
Surname


Activity
ID (PK, AI)
Name

given_activity
A_ID (FK to Activity ID)
I_ID (FK to Instructor ID)
Slot (PK)
```

we have designed our tables like this, but we could not satisfy this condition;

"a instructor should not give an activity at the same time"

how could we change our tables?

Comment: you mean to say ,in given_activity, an instructor cannot have same slot ???
Please elaborate.

Comment: yes an instructor can not have same slot values in the given_activity table

Answer (score 0):

your primary key can help you
create a primary key on table given_activity

```
PRIMARY KEY(a_id,i_id)
```

Comment: by doing this will i be able to satisfy the condition?

Comment: Make this primary key unique and yes it will fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The condition:

*an instructor should not give an activity at the same time*

Is saying that there are no duplicates for instructor/slot in `given_activity`.  You can accomplish this with a unique index/constraint:

```
create unique index unq_givenactivity_instructor_slot on given_activity(I_ID, slot);
```

Answer (score 0):

@davejal

making a_id and i_id PK will cause that

"an instructor can not give an activity in different times"

```
a_id (PK)     i_id (PK)      slot
1             2              10-12
1             2              12-14
```